# VBA difference between "Double" and "Variant" array types when transposing

Tags: arrays, vba, types, transpose, variant

I would like someone to explain why VBA code works if arrays are defined as Variant type but not if they are defined as Double type, when transposing the array.
I have this simple test code:

```
Option Base 1
Sub testDELput()
    Dim c() As Variant
    Dim d() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    ReDim c(5)
    For i = 1 To 5        'assign test values to c
        c(i) = 10 * i
    Next
    ReDim d(5, 1)
    d = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(c)
End Sub
```

This code works fine, d is a column vector with the elements of c
However, if I change the array declarations to Double, i.e.:

```
Dim c() As Double
Dim d() As Double
```

I got the following error:

[image]

I cannot understand why. Can anybody explain please?

The same happens if I redim c like this:

```
ReDim c(1, 5)
```

Thanks for the attention

Comment: Because Variant can contain Double, but Double cannot contain Variant?

Comment: If you read the manual, it quite clearly states that the transpose method type is variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding about array becomes strange if you do not know what `Transpose` function returns.

As Microsoft states [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.transpose), it returns a `Variant`!

```
Sub testDoubleArray()
  Dim d() As Double, i As Long

  ReDim d(5, 1)
  For i = 1 To 5
        d(i, 1) = i * 100
  Next i
  
  Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(d), "|") 'just to visually see its content (after transforming in 1D array - Variant type)
End Sub
```

Then, in the example you try, the `mismatch` error comes from the fact that you cannot load a `Double` array with a `Variant` type one:

```
Sub testDELput()
    Dim c() As Double
    Dim d() As Variant 'because this is what Transpose returns!
    Dim i As Integer
    ReDim c(5): Debug.Print LBound(c): Stop
    For i = 1 To 5        'assign test values to c
        c(i) = 10 * i
    Next
    ReDim d(5, 1)
    
    With Application
       Debug.Print Join(.Transpose(.Transpose(c)), "|"): Stop '1D Variant type
        d = .Transpose(c)
    End With
    
    Debug.Print LBound(d), UBound(d), UBound(d, 2)
End Sub
```

You can load a `Double` array from another `Double` one, as you can see in the next sub:

```
Sub testDoubleArray()
  Dim d() As Double, c() As Double, i As Long

  ReDim d(5, 1)
  For i = 1 To 5
        d(i, 1) = i * 10
  Next i
  
  Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(d), "|") 'just to visually see its content (after tranforming in 1D array)
  ReDim c(5, 1)
  c = d
  
  Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(c), "|")
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thank for your clever answer. I missed the fact that transpose function returns a Variant type. Anyway, Transpose function would be more clever if it returned the same type of array that it receives as input, I think...

Comment: Apart from this question, Is there a benefit to explicitly declare the array as double? for me it is a peace for mind to keep it declared as variant.

Comment: @Guille A lot of things can be done better according to our taste, but in real world we must learn how to work with them in the way they are. Or to improve them, if we can... :)

Comment: @Waleed Declaring a variable as `Variant`, because it needs to be prepared for keeping almost anything, **will load the memory excessively**, compared to a declaration for a specific type. Of course, when you know what data type will be handled... And something else: If you intend to load the respective array variable **only with numbers** and, by mistake, your code tries to load a string, you will be warned.

Answer (score 4):

[`WorksheetFunction.Transpose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.transpose) is declared to return a (single) `Variant`:

```vb
Function Transpose(Arg1) As Variant
```

A single `Variant` can contain all sorts of things, including an array of other data types.

The compiler knows that, so it does not raise a compile-time error immediately. It has to wait till runtime to see if, by any chance, that returned `Variant` happens to contain an array of `Double`s, which is the only thing that your `d()` can contain.

It so happens that no, the `Variant` that `Transpose` returns does not contain an array of `Double`s. It contains an array of `Variant`s. Your `d()` cannot contain that, so a runtime type mismatch error occurs.

If `Transpose` were declared as explicitly returning an array of variants:

```vb
Function Transpose(Arg1) As Variant()
```

then instead of a runtime error 13 you would get a compile time error "Can't assign to array", because this time the compiler does not have to wait till runtime to check if the returned value is in fact compatible with `d()`. It can see straight away that it isn't.

The only way you would be able to assign to a `d() As Double` is if you had a function that explicitly returns a `Double()` (not even `Single()` or `Long()`), or a function that returns a single `Variant` that at the time of the call will happen to contain an array of `Double()`:

```vb
Sub testDELput()
    Dim d() As Double
    
    d = returns_double_array_as_double_array()    'Works
    d = returns_double_array_as_variant()         'Works
    
    'd = returns_variant_array_as_variant()       'Run-time error 13: Type mismatch
    'd = returns_variant_array_as_variant_array() 'Compile-time error: Can't assign to array
End Sub

Private Function returns_double_array_as_double_array() As Double()
    Dim arr() As Double
    returns_double_array_as_double_array = arr
End Function

Private Function returns_double_array_as_variant() As Variant
    Dim arr() As Double
    returns_double_array_as_variant = arr
End Function

Private Function returns_variant_array_as_variant() As Variant
    Dim arr() As Variant
    returns_variant_array_as_variant = arr
End Function

Private Function returns_variant_array_as_variant_array() As Variant()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    returns_variant_array_as_variant_array = arr
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

My experience in the past has been similar, and I default to using the 'Variant' data type in situations where I'm programmatically changing the values contained in the variables you've denoted c() and d().

I understand that you're eluding to the fact that you would have expected the 'Double' data types being used should have otherwise allowed you to store the elements being declared.

So whilst 'Variant' can store different value types including integer, string, and dates etc. the 'Double' data type is specific to representing double-precision floating-point numbers.

Your code as far as I can tell is likely yielding integer numbers in the final result and NOT floating point numbers hence the Type mismatch error e.g. c(5) =  10 * 5  yields 50 (integer) and not 50.00 (double). You need to either coerce the result to be a float type e.g. 10 * 5.00 = 50.00 or dim c() and d() as an Integer.

Simply stating the data type as Double is likely not performing this conversion from Integer to Double automatically as one might assume.

Comment: Immediately after `10 * 5` yields 50 (integer), it gets stored in `c(i)`, converting it to `Double`. It's easy to see that this step completes fine. What does not complete is assigning to `d`. At that point `c` contains an array of definitely doubles.